# Is there a grammar mistake in "These restaurants are for people who are always in haste."?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence, "These restaurants are for people who are always in haste." grammatically correct? Can I use verb-to-be before "in haste"? Thank you so much!

Comment: The grammar is a hair "starchy", but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: how about "on the go"?

Comment: These restaurants are for busy people.

Comment: _In haste_ tends to occur as a comment on the pragmatics of the utterance, as when someone uses it as a close in a note: _In haste, Letitia_.

Comment: I would phrase it as "... always in a hurry."

Comment: @JohnLawler - *In haste* is also used as an adverb in a sentence, for example, "Marry in haste, repent at leisure." // Daisy, it's grammatically correct but a little unnatural.

Comment: Probably a fixed phrase, like many proverbs are.

Answer (score 1):

From the corpus COCA https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/, I get only 5 occurrences containing "be(am,is,are,were,was) in haste", but get 742 instances with "be in a hurry". So "be in haste" is rarely used if not mistaken and it is safe to use "be in a hurry".